# How can I remove multiple columns from Jtable in Java?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecolumn

I need to remove 2 columns from a Jtable.

If I do:

```
try { 
jTable5.setModel(dtm);
jTable5.removeColumn(jTable5.getColumnModel().getColumn(5));
jTable5.removeColumn(jTable5.getColumnModel().getColumn(6));
jTable5.setVisible(true);
} 
catch (Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error");
}
```

Then "Error" is displayed.

But If I do:

```
try { 
jTable5.setModel(dtm);
jTable5.removeColumn(jTable5.getColumnModel().getColumn(5));
jTable5.setVisible(true);
} 
catch (Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error");
}
```

Error is not displayed, and table is set to visible correctly. It seems that I cant remove two columns from a model using the `removeColumn()` method twice.

I have noticed that there is a removeColumnSelectionInterval(), should I use this one?

Any ideas?

Comment: am assuming that in your table there are total 6 Columns & due to which when you remove column 5 after that if you try to get column 6 at that time it triggers error because now there are 5 colums

Comment: 1) Use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  The indentation of the code is intended to help people understand the program flow. 2) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example).

Comment: That is right, I tried removing column 6 first and then column 5 and it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: Tip: Add @Swapnil (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: Please try getColumnIndex(Object Identifier) to get column index and use the column index to remove column.

Answer (score 2):

first, you should make use of the exception, don't just show "error", show `e.getMessage()`,

```
try { 
jTable5.setModel(dtm);
jTable5.removeColumn(jTable5.getColumnModel().getColumn(5));
jTable5.removeColumn(jTable5.getColumnModel().getColumn(6));
jTable5.setVisible(true);
} 
catch (Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Error " + e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();//shows more detailed stack trace
}
```

and use `e.printStackTrace()`...

2nd, i think when u are removing the first column, then the other columns get shifted,
so when you remove column 5, then there is no column 6 because it was shifted and its 5 too now, thats what cause the error,

so a wild guess is to use

```
jTable5.removeColumn(jTable5.getColumnModel().getColumn(5));
jTable5.removeColumn(jTable5.getColumnModel().getColumn(5));
```

yes, remove 5 twice.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have 7 columns and removing them by the index. When removed the index count -1, then you can't use an index value higher than size. Change to

```
jTable5.removeColumn(jTable5.getColumnModel().getColumn(6));
jTable5.removeColumn(jTable5.getColumnModel().getColumn(5));
```